# How to discuss the maximum Area of Internal rectangular in an irregular region?

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

How to discuss the maximum Area of Internal rectangular in an irregular region?

such as Fan-shape,or the region....

Comment: Do you mean "How does one find the largest rectangle in the interior of an irregular region?"?

Comment: yes,I did not know the correct expression.